# Is a memory leak possible?

Tags: internet-explorer, memory-usage

We have a group of employees who are required to use IE (8, 9 or 10 doesn't seem to make a difference in the issue). When they navigate to the website they are suppose to use, an application loads that uses Silverlight.

During the use of this application, the computer becomes bogged down, usually to a halt, rendering the program and computer unusable.

A look in Task Manager finds that iexplorer.exe hits 1,200,000 K of Memory (Private Working Set). Shutting down IE eventually removes the iexplorer.exe process. Restarting the browser and navigating the to same site will put the iexplorer.exe process at 120,00K Memory... this number, through use of the Silverlight application, will cause the iexplorer.exe process to grow its Memory usage, 200,000K, 430,000K, 780,000K, etc... it never seems to go down, even if the application is idol.

Is this a memory leak in the application?

Comment: I'd say the application is at fault and you should be talking to those developers.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate the reason you need at least to take detailed trace of the processes, we can't just say "problem is in application" or "there is a problem with internet exploder".

Problem might be in anywhere - in IE, OS, Silverlight, Application logic. Hard to say without deep analysis. If same application works without problems on other PC's - probably the problem will be in IE, OS, Silverlight.

Comment: Could you recommend a tool to do this process tracing, I'm not sure how to go about that? It's not our application, we aren't the ones that developed it. We are trying to figure out if the issue is on our end or the application's end.

Comment: This may help - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx